# Thread is being abortted while deleting folders

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using web service method to run scripts it generated the some unwanted folders i want to delete folders after or before the script runs.

```
ProcessStatus newProcess =
                    new ProcessStatus(
                            String.Format(
                                "{0}, started:{1}",
                                projectName, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:m:ss")
                                )
                            );
newProcess.buildData = new BuildHelper(deviceName, projectName, owner, deviceFolder,  Constants.serverContentpath, Constants.buildInfoFilePath);
ProcessStatuses processStatus = new ProcessStatuses();
ArrayList allProcesses = processStatus.Get();
ArrayList.Synchronized(allProcesses).Add(newProcess);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                        new WaitCallback(processStatus.startProcessing),
                        new object[] { newProcess, allProcesses }
                        );
//Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate {
//    processStatus.startProcessing(new object[] { newProcess, allProcesses });
//}));
//th.Start();
processStatus = null;
newProcess = null;
_deviceBuildMonitor = null;
```

Comment: We need a bit more info than just source code.

Comment: when i clkick build , I am executing the python script uisng asp.net C# using webmethod. i call the delefoders method before running the script it deletes the folders, throws the thread has being aborted exception.

Comment: you should edit your post and add proper markdown formatting - see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first reframe your question as i understand.

Your webservice has created some temp files are you spawing off a thred to do some cleanup operations.

If your webservice is hosted on an IIS server then the problem could be that you IIS App pool is restarting on deletion(**File Change Notification**) of the directory. Try executing this code either in your app start event or before you try deleting the directory

```
var theRuntime = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
var fcmField = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_fcm", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var fcm = fcmField.GetValue(theRuntime);
fcmField.FieldType.GetMethod("Stop", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(fcm, null);
```

Comment: Thanks so much its working miracle to me i struggled 3 days for this..